# How to reconstruct array from np.unique

Tags: numpy

From [document of `unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), I know I can get `return_index` and `return_inverse`. It seems like COO matrix compressing.

I wonder how can I reconstruct the array by numpy. I find I can do it with `np.fromfunction`, but I must write a method to determine every item of the result array. I want to know if there is a easy/neat way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `np.fromfunction` is needed. The documentation actually gives you the example to reconstruct the array from `return_inverse`:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
u, indices = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
u # ==> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
indices # ==> array([0, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1])
u[indices] # ==> array([1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2])
```